# Windows Task Scheduler is not able to create a pdf from EPM

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, sap-epm

We are scheduling a distribution offline using windows task scheduler from EPM.

So basically it's a daily report. it creates the file from EPM (excel add in) and email to the users.

We have two formats: workbook and PDF.

The workbook works fine with distribute now and schedule distribution.

But the pdf format works fine only with distribute now option.

The schedule is not working with pdf format.

No errors, the task runs successful. But no file is getting created.

So we did a trace and it says "the pdf is still locked"

The weird thing is if we use a different user's Microsoft account(from different domain/client), it works perfectly. In all the above cases the EPM runs with the same user.(we only switched the Microsoft account)

The only time it worked is when we just switch the Microsoft excel account with a different domain user.

Office subscription is not an issue.
Dcom is configured correctly.
User has right privilege.

To be honest, i hit a dead end here.

Office subscription is not an issue.

Dcom is configured correctly.

User has right privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the issue hasn't been resolved completely, we have found a workaround.

Once you schedule the distribution, log out of the Microsoft excel.

Then the task will create the pdf and send it to the users

Comment: I would be clearer if you can make it as step-by-step instruction.

Comment: Do you want step by step instructions on the work around or on how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The second one, since the first one is already clear from your answer.

Comment: We have a report and this report uses data from SAP BPC database. This report will go to Leadership team.

Comment: EPM add in was chosen as the solution to distribute this report automatically via email in PDF format. EPM has functionality called "distribute"

Comment: Let's consider an user "A"

Comment: User A logged into her computer; Opened the Microsoft Excel; Log on to EPM; Schedule the distribution of the report offline by selecting workbook format; The task got scheduled successfully. It ran and completed successfully. We saw the report being created and sent to users via mail successfully; We did the same by selecting the report with PDF format; The task got scheduled successfully and ran successfully. But no pdf file was created nor it was being sent to users.

Comment: Working Scenario 1:   User A logged into her machine: opened the excel. Switched the excel account with another User (let's consider another user "B") This user B is not from the same domain as User A(means user A mail id is usera@abc.com and user B mail id is userb@xyz.com) Then user A logged into EPM. Scheduled the distribution by selecting "PDF" format. It worked. The file was created and sent to users as well on the completion of task ran successfully.

Comment: Before move to working Scenario 2, we tried the above steps with the two users from the same domain(usera@abc.com and userc@abc.com) it didn't work

Comment: Working Scenario 2:     User a logged into her machine: opened the excel and log on to EPM. Scheduled the distribution with pdf format; Task scheduled successfully. Log out from the excel. And waited for task to start and it did start and ran successfully. This time the pdf file was created and sent to users via mail as well.

Comment: When we kept the trace and whenever it didn't work, the trace file showed the same error " the pdf is still locked"

Answer (score 0):

Windows privacy protection is blocking the pdf generation because of sensitivity labels.

The print option won't work because of this.

The solution is to use different virtual pdf printer other than Microsoft print to pdf